# Has gnome-calendar got notifications?

Tags: calendar

Is there a functionality of `gnome-calendar` (in `Xenial`) to sending notifications on events like `notify-send` style ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at this time.  However, there is a development road-map at https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Calendar/Roadmap#Future which suggests that alarms will be added in future releases.